# How to use different shells in one script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcl

I am trying to write a script like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
.... some lines

#!/bin/tclsh
.... some lines
```

How can I handle this?

Initially, I had 8 scripts with different shells, and 1 run.sh script. Now I am trying to combine 8 scripts in one script with functions, and I wanted to have an individual shell for each the functions.

Comment: How do you want to handle this? `#!/bin/tclsh` is just a comment.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to keep things in one file? It's going to make things a lot more difficult for you unless the code in at least one part is extremely short.

Comment: You can't easily do what you're trying to do. You could write two different shell scripts, then write a third that calls one then the other. You could accomplish effectively the same thing with a single shell script by writing out code to a temporary file and then calling that with your second shell. Etc...

Comment: Initially, I had 8 scripts with different shells, and 1 run.sh script. Now I am trying to combine 8 scripts in one script with functions, and I wanted to have an individual shell for each function.

Comment: I think you should not try to smash all "shell" code into a single file. Treat different shell programs like the different languages that they are, and allow each to have their own space. You wouldn't put Java and C code into a single file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this, where `tclsh` is reading its commands from its `stdin` as passed to it by `sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hi, from sh"

/usr/bin/tclsh <<'EOF'
puts $tcl_version
exit
EOF

echo "Bye, from sh"
```

**Output**

```
Hi, from sh
8.5
Bye, from sh
```

Comment: Nearly perfect answer. Minor point: The OP wanted to combine sh and Tcl, not bash and Tcl. You just have to fix your `#!`.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, thank you for pointing that out. I have corrected it.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just, I can have different tclsh paths (which tclsh).

Comment: One more question. Is there a way to use this method with tclsh and other one?
Like

#!/usr/bin/tclsh

echo "Hi, from tclsh"

/usr/bin/<other shell> <<'EOF'
puts ...
exit
EOF

echo "Bye, from tclsh"

Comment: Tcl does not _exactly_ have heredocs, but in Tcl you'd use [`exec`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm) to invoke an external command and pass input to it.

Comment: @glennjackman Thank you for your thoughts. I know you have a lot of experience with `tcl` so please feel free to add a better answer - I'm always happy to learn and not concerned about rep points or any ego/nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bash or zsh instead of plain old Bourne Shell, you can do this:

```
tclsh <(cat <<'EOF'
puts "This is in Tcl [info patchlevel]"
puts $env(PATH)
EOF
)
```

The advantage of this is that Tcl will see that as a *file* and not standard input and so will not be in interactive mode; that's absolutely recommended for all scripted use. In standard Bourne Shell, you instead have to provide the input to tclsh via stdin and that can be a bit trickier from a scripting perspective:

```
tclsh <<'EOF'
puts "This is in Tcl [info patchlevel]"
puts $env(PATH)
EOF
```